# getting NULL value for string 'marketing' and 'makeing' as soundex drops vowels only as both have same soundex string value

Tags: mysql, sql, fuzzy-comparison, soundex

Write a query to return the list of employee IDs with incorrectly spelled departments, from the Emp Master table. correct data is in Dept_Master with no foreign key.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Emp_Master as orig
LEFT OUTER JOIN Dept_Master as correct
ON SOUNDEX(orig.Department) = SOUNDEX(correct.Department_Name)
WHERE orig.Department  NOT IN (SELECT Department_Name FROM Dept_Master)
```

tried this but getting NULL value for string 'marketing' and 'makeing' as soundex drops vowels only as both have same soundex string value.
how can I solve it?

Comment: [SOUNDEX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) is a century-old algorithm originally designed for fuzzy matching of North American proper names. It was designed to help telephone directory assistance operators look up subscribers (telephone users) based on how their names sound over the 8Khz telephone system of yesteryear. It's quirky at best, and designed for presenting alternatives to a human user to select. Your words *marketing* and *makeing* differ significantly in how they sound: one contains *r* and *t* and the other does not.

Comment: This is why God created foreign keys. Mismatched names aren't the real problem. Not using numeric ID columns and storing the foreign key value in the child table is the problem.

Comment: You don’t need the join at all, the WHERE clause is all you need

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct orig.Emp_ID,(orig.department) from Emp_Master as orig,Dept_Master as correct 
where orig.Department not in (select Department_Name from Dept_Master);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].